# Android Eclipse Error -- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_column' in package

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, sdk

I face an error that is sabotaging my whole project:

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_column' in package

This was the first ever error I got in the Project. Well, at first it didn't bother me but then as I continued with my project It became more prominent. When I started defining the objects in my app using findViewById, I noticed that no automatic suggestions were coming up and correct me if this is wrong:

```
TextView Name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.NameLabel);
TextView Surname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.SurnameLabel);
TextView Profession = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ProfessionLabel);
TextView Contacts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ContactLabel);
```

I got the error that the Labels cannot be resolved or a field despite adding them and double checking names back to the layout, but nope. I searched online and I found that there would be no automatic responce either because I hadn't saved it and I knew I'd saved it then. So something was wrong with the XML file: yep.

After checking online for so many solutions but none of them worked (unless I'm doing them incorrectly) but there was none specific to my problem. So I thought - "You know what, why don't I clean it as a last resort?" I did and it made things a lot worse, now the R cannot be resolved or as a field and same goes for activity_main_screen in the MainScreen.java file. I searched what could be causing these errors independently and I got the same response, there was something wrong with the XML file: ...yep.

Please help me, now I face 9 errors because of the xml file, what could be wrong??? Here is is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.DenzDevAppz.cardbeta"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/MainApp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/MainLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Contact"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="224dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="true"
        android:rowCount="9"
        android:rowOrderPreserved="true" >

        <TextView             <------------(error)
            android:id="@+id/ProfessionLabel"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_row="1"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_gravity="left|top"
            app:layout_row="2"
            android:text="Profession:"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/NameLabel"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_gravity="left|top"
            app:layout_row="0"
            android:text="Name:"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/BusinessLabel"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_row="2"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_gravity="left|top"
            app:layout_row="4"
            android:text="Business:"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LocationLabel"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_row="3"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_gravity="left|top"
            app:layout_row="5"
            android:text="Location:"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/NameDataRetreiver"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_row="0"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_gravity="left|top"
            app:layout_row="0"
            android:text="None"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SurnameDataRetrevier"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_row="1"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_gravity="left|top"
            app:layout_row="2"
            android:text="None"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/BusinessDataRetreiver"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_row="2"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_gravity="left|top"
            app:layout_row="4"
            android:text="None"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/LocationDataRetreiver"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_row="3"
            app:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:text="None"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ContactsLabel"
            android:layout_width="84dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_row="4"
            app:layout_column="0"
            app:layout_gravity="left|top"
            app:layout_row="7"
            android:text="Contacts:"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ContactDataRetrevL2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_row="4"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_gravity="left|top"
            app:layout_row="8"
            android:text="--------------------"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ContactDataRetrevL3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_row="5"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_gravity="left|top"
            app:layout_row="9"
            android:text="--------------------"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ContactDataRetrevL4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_row="6"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_gravity="left|top"
            app:layout_row="10"
            android:text="---------------------"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ContactDataRetrevL1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_row="7"
            app:layout_column="1"
            app:layout_gravity="left|top"
            app:layout_row="7"
            android:text="--------------------"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </GridLayout>

    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/Card_Holder"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.17"
        android:background="#C0C0C0" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.73"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        app:layout_row="0"
        android:text="What would you like to do?" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="269dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="188dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ImportContactButton"
                android:layout_width="266dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:text="Add/Import Contact" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/DeleteContactButton"
                android:layout_width="266dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="Delete Contact" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ViewContactButton"
                android:layout_width="266dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="View Contact" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ContactBusinessButton"
                android:layout_width="266dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="Contact Business/Card" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please help, if you've got any suggestions , its greatly appreciated and as I've got a deadline approaching the end of this week, an answer is seriously appreciated.

Thank you.

And if you are interested in the rest of the errors here there are:

> SurnameLabel cannot be resolved or is not a field   -MainScreen.java -Java Problem
>   ProfessionLabel cannot be resolved or is not a field    -MainScreen.java    -Java Problem
>   NameLabel cannot be resolved or is not a field -MainScreen.java -Java Problem
>   activity_main_screen cannot be resolved or is not a field   -MainScreen.java -Java Problem
>   ContactLabel cannot be resolved or is not a field -MainScreen.java -Java Problem
>   action_settings cannot be resolved or is not a field -MainScreen.java -Java Problem
>   main_screen cannot be resolved or is not a field -MainScreen.java -Java Problem ||||| error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_column' in package -Android AAPT Problem

Thank you sooooooooo much.

Comment: Change xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.DenzDevAppz.cardbeta" to xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: Nope, no luck. Now I have another error saying: Element type "LinearLayout" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/
 >" even though its been done properly.